# How to include Ruby string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, embedding

I have the ruby code:

```
<%= "hello #{@namevar}" if condition %>
```

I can include ruby snippet in JS in the following way-

```
<script>
    var v1="<%= @user.name  %>"
</script>
```

But can't embed the previous code in JavaScript.

I have tried the following:

```
var v2="<%= \"hello #{@namevar}\" if condition %>";
```

But didn't work.

Thanx.

Comment: What do you want to do? Assign the string to a variable depending on a condition?

Comment: I want this
`<%= "hello #{@namevar}" if condition %>` to get into a JS variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is almost correct, you don't need to escape the double quotes inside the ruby code though:

```
var v2="<%= "Our funding ask is #{@startup.funding_ask_text}." if @startup.try(:funding_ask_text) %>";
```

Comment: Thanx. this worked. I didn't event expect it to work according to conventions. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

**Asset Pipeline**

You can't include ruby code in your asset pipeline

If you want to include "naked" ruby, you'll have to use `.js.erb` and put the file in your `views` directory. The reason for this is because the asset pipeline can be [`precompiled`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), which will render the Ruby code useless

---

**Vars**

If you want to use rails-based data in your JS, you'll have to first render the data in your views, and then call it from JS (like Bachan's answer)

You can use the [`Gon` gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) for this

Comment: `var v1="<%= @user.name  %>"` wasn't a problem at all. So what do u want to say?

Comment: I don't want to "say" anything - I was trying to give you some idea as to how to include vars in your asset JS. Including naked ruby code in your asset pipeline is bad practice & will lead to problems in future

Comment: Ok. thanx for the elaboration. +1

Answer (score 0):

In your layout add a hidden_field

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user_name', @user.name%>
```

And in script

```
var v1 = $('#user_name').val()
```

Comment: This should be simple. But you r giving such a solution for which I need an extra dom element!!!

This definitely is not the solution.